# Hibernate hbm2ddl schema creation and Maven tests

Tags: spring, hibernate, unit-testing, maven

I try to use the following Hibernate property to create the database schema.

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
```

This is a Maven Java EE (Hibernate/Spring) project that consists of Maven unit tests which validates the database schema at the beginning. That means database schema is validated (and thus deployment fails) before it is created.

How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to understand what you want to do, but if your DDL is generated before the test phase (and it should be the case if you do this at process-classes phase), it should exist when your tests are running.

```
<execution>
        <phase>process-classes</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>hbm2ddl</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
```

Comment: I would prefer to do this in either the `generate-sources` or `generate-resources` phase.